# Unattended ubiquity seed url can only be found via ip but not via DNS name

Tags: system-installation, dns, dhcp, preseed, ubiquity

I am able to install my linux ubuntu / mint in an unattended way with preseeding via a grub command line like

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz toram ip=dhcp -- automatic-ubiquity url=http://192.168.178.38:8080/preseed/linux-unattended.seed
```

If I try to replace the ip in the url with let's say `http://preseed.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/linux-unattended.seed` it doesn't work. It is failing to resolve the DNS name.

I've also tried naming DNS servers explicitly by replacing `ip=dhcp` with `ip=::::::dhcp:8.8.8.8:8.8.4.4`. Doesn't seem to change anything.

Any clues why the DNS resolving for the preseed file doesn't work even though DNS in general (also during installation of the system once the preseed file has been loaded) works?

**Edit:** I've verified that this problem exists in ubuntu 20.04 and linux mint 20.1. For ubuntu I've booted from usb and changed the boot commandline as follows:

```
initrd=/casper/initrd boot=casper ip=dhcp -- automatic-ubiquity url=http://preseed.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/linux-unattended.seed
```

(The url is just a placeholder and doesn't contain my real seed file). Again exchanging the hostname with my ip which basically points to a nginx everything works as expectd.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome.

Comment: OK @David I'll check whether this also affects Ubuntu Focal. So far my seed file is 100% compatible with ubuntu but I didn't try to use the dns lookup there. Will update my question once I verified.